# using sbcl schedule-timer with sly

Tags: timer, emacs, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I want to use a timer to periodically print info to the repl (and do some other things).
SBCL 2.0.1
Emacs 26.1
sly 1.0.0-beta-3

(I can't create a sly tag...)

in sly-repl:

```
(defvar *timer* (make-timer (lambda ()
                              (write-line ".")
                              (force-output))))

(schedule-timer *timer* 2 :repeat-interval 1)`
```

and works fine - after 2 seconds, "." is printed

in timer-test.lisp:

```
(defvar *timer* (make-timer (lambda ()
                              (write-line ".")
                              (force-output))))
(schedule-timer *timer* 2 :repeat-interval 1)`
```

compiles fine

when I execute the `schedule-timer` form, the REPL tells me:

`Timer #<TIMER {1002C5EB33}> failed to interrupt thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "slynk-worker" FINISHED values: T {1002C3DFA3}>.`

I don't know enough about threads in SBCL to sort this out. Is there a simple way to get a scheduled timer (in a file) to output to the REPL?

with thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting help - I should have done that

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of your code which tries to use some SWANK functionality to find out what the REPL thread is and schedule the timer in that thread.  Note that this won't work with SLY as far as I can tell because SLY has different package names at least.  However it may provide a clue and it's too long to be a comment.

Note also that I don't know if this is the right way of finding the REPL thread, or if the REPL thread actually persists for any length of time.

If `repl-thread-maybe` fails to find a candidate thread, it returns `t`, which causes `make-timer` to run the timer in its own thread.  This is safe I think, but will mean that any output from the timer (assuming that's what you are after) goes somewhere other than the REPL.

Anyway, here it is for what it's worth

```
;;;;
;;;

(in-package :cl-user)

#-(and SBCL SWANK)
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (error "Not SBCL / not SWANK"))

(defun repl-thread-maybe (&key (repl-thread-name "repl-thread")
                               (fallback-value t))
  ;; I have no idea if this is the right way to find the REPL thread,
  ;; but it kind of works.
  (or (find-if (lambda (thread)
                 (string-equal (swank/backend:thread-name thread)
                               repl-thread-name))
               (swank/backend:all-threads))
      fallback-value))

(defparameter *timer* (make-timer (lambda ()
                                    (write-line ".")
                                    (force-output))
                                  :thread (repl-thread-maybe)))

(schedule-timer *timer* 2 :repeat-interval 1)
```